# Updating common fields in models

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, design-patterns, asp.net-core

I have some problems with duplicated code.
I have multiple models that have same properties like this:

```
public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
public DateTimeOffset ModifiedDate { get; set; }
public virtual AppUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
public virtual AppUser ModifiedBy { get; set; }
```

Now I am writing identical code to update this fields in multiple actions of controllers, like this:

```
model.CreatedBy = user;
model.CreatedDate = now;
model.ModifiedBy = user;
model.ModifiedDate = now;
```

I am wondering is there any method or pattern to avoid this duplicate codes? Is any best practice in this situation?
I am using `EntityFramework` and `ASP.net Core Web API`. (if that make sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a base model like `AuditedEntity` with those properties, and the rest of the models inherited from it:

```
public class AuditedEntity
{
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual AppUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual AppUser ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

In your service layer you can have a method `WriteAuditInformation(AuditedEntity model)` to call in `Create()` and `Update()` methods:

```
public void WriteAuditInformation(AuditedEntity model)
{
    model.CreatedBy = user;
    model.CreatedDate = now;
    model.ModifiedBy = user;
    model.ModifiedDate = now;
}
```

Another approach would be if you have access to `user` variable in your context class is override `SaveChanges()` method:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditedEntity>();
    foreach (var item in entities)
    {
        if (item.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            item.CreatedBy = user;
            item.CreatedDate = now;
            item.ModifiedBy = user;
            item.ModifiedDate = now;
        }
        else if (item.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            item.ModifiedBy = user;
            item.ModifiedDate = now;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I accept your answer for `SaveChanges` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create interface, for example:

```
public interface IMetaDataHolder{
    DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
    DateTimeOffset ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    AppUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    AppUser ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

add it to your models, and inside base controller you can use something like that:

```
protected void AssignMetaData(IMetaDataHolder metaDataHolder){
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow; //or whatever
    var user = Session.User; //or whatever

    metaDataHolder.CreatedBy = user;
    metaDataHolder.CreatedDate = now;
    metaDataHolder.ModifiedBy = user;
    metaDataHolder.ModifiedDate = now; 
}
```

This way in your Action Methods you can call just AssignMetaData method instead of duplicating assignment calls.